# Unbiased estimators of the log odds

Tags: mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, unbiased-estimator, logarithm, odds

In the book of Lehmann and Casella (2003) page 83, a random variable $X$ is distributed according to the binomial distribution $Bin(n,p)$, $n$ the number of trials and $p$ the success probability.

Now they say  suppose $g(p)$ is a function of $p$ which our interest lies, and let $\delta(X)$ be an estimator of $g(p)$ then $\delta$ is unbiased for $g(p)$ if 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n\delta(k)\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^k=g(p) \quad \forall p
\end{equation}
 Now take $g(p)=1/p$, we immediately see that there is no unbiased estimator of $1/p$ for all $p$, for if $p\rightarrow 0$, the left hand side of the equation tends to $\delta(0)$ and the right side to $\infty$.

My question is, is there an unbiased estimator $\log (p/(1-p))$? maybe not for all $p$?

Answer (score 2):

For the case $g(p)=1/p$, a more rigorous proof for nonexistence of unbiased estimators is [For the binomial distribution, why does no unbiased estimator exist for $1/p$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/for-the-binomial-distribution-why-does-no-unbiased-estimator-exist-for-1-p).  With $g(p)=\log\frac{p}{1-p}$, you could mimick your argument using limits when $p \to 0$, since $\log\frac{p}{1-p} = \log p - \log (1-p)$ which goes to $-\infty$ when p goes to zero. But let us try a more rigorous proof:

Let $x \sim \mathcal{Binom}(n,p)$ with $p \in (0,1)$, and let $\delta()$ be some estimator. Write $\theta= \log\frac{p}{1-p}$ with inverse $p=\frac{e^\theta}{1+e^\theta}$. Then if $\delta$ is unbiased for $\theta$ we must have 
$$
    \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \delta(k) - \theta=0
$$
Rewrite this as
$$ \sum \binom{n}{k} e^{k \theta}\delta(k) -\theta (1+e^\theta)^n =0. 
$$ Now use the power series for the exponential function $e^\theta = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\theta^j}{j!}$, and also expand $(1+e^\theta)^n$ using the binomial theorem, we get
$$
\sum_k \binom{n}{k} \delta(k) \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{k^j \theta^j}{j!} =
\sum_k \binom{n}{k} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{k^j \theta^{j+1}}{j!}.
$$ Now use the [identity theorem for power series](https://planetmath.org/identitytheoremofpowerseries), if two power series are identical on an open interval, then all their coefficients are identical. But for the two power series above, the RHS have a constant term of zero, while the LHS have a constant term $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\delta(k)$. So for $\delta$ to be an unbiased estimator of $\theta$, this sum must be 0. That would require either $\delta=0$ (which is unbiased only for $\theta=0$), or $\delta$ to take both positive and negative values. This does not give an impossibility yet.

Take the particular case $n=2$. Then peel off coefficients from the power series corresponding to $\theta^0, \theta^1, \theta^2$. Setting them equal gives a linear system of equations in three unknowns $\delta_0, \delta_1, \delta_2$. Without details, I find the system 
\begin{align}
   \delta_0 + 2\delta_1 + \delta_2&=0 \\
   2\delta_1 +2\delta_2&=2\\
\delta_1+2\delta_2&=4
\end{align} with solution $\delta_0=-2, \delta_1=0, \delta_2=2$. But now it is easy to calculate that this estimator isn't unbiased.

I will see if I can come back and generalize this argument for all $n$, but it does not seem straightforward.