# No unbiased estimators

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, unbiased-estimator

Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be a sample from the Poisson distribution with the parameter $\theta$.
How to prove that there are no unbiased estimators for $\theta^{−2}$?
I have no idea that why there are **no at all**.

Comment: Most functions of $\theta$ do not enjoy the existence of an unbiased estimator.

Comment: Use the methods illustrated by the similar question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87107.

Comment: It would imply $\varphi(0)=+\infty$...